# Votes are (Rarely) Attached to the Answer I Didn't Vote for (or against)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting

Once in a while, I'm browsing on the Stack Overflow trilogy, and I vote up an answer or two and then refresh the page. What happens is that the votes have attached themselves to answers I *didn't* vote for, and have been unattached to the ones I *did* vote for.

---

**Repro steps:**

Unknown. Unable to reproduce consistently.

**Expected result:**

Votes stay attached to the answer I voted for.

**Actual result:**

Votes occasionally attach to the wrong answer.

**Browser and OS:**

Safari 4.0.4 for Mac; Mac OS X 10.5.8

---

**More irrelevant thoughts:**

Personally, I see 3 places where there could be a problem.

1. Browser problem (rendering incorrectly for some weird reason)
<s>2. Problem with the voting script (recording a vote for the wrong answer)</s> (fixed upon refresh)
3. Problem with the output script (sending incorrect output even though DB is right)

If I experience this problem again, I should be able to eliminate either #2 or #3, depending on whether the error is persistent or not. (I'm not sure at this time if it only displays incorrectly for one instance or if it does so consistently)

**@SOFU team:** If you feel inclined to ignore this bug report because of the lack of repro steps (presumably, you guys haven't experienced the same problem) until I get more info, please do so.

Comment: *Sleepvoting* should be recognized as a serious illness finally.

Comment: Quite late, but maybe related: [Voting counted on wrong answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175388/voting-counted-on-wrong-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I've seen something like this with Safari 4 (particularly when I've taken some time to research whether an answer was good enough for my vote, or where I've been interrupted by non-internet things like work or family) but could never reproduce reliably. What I *can* say is that refreshing straight after allows you to check whether your vote is on the right answer, and if it's gone awry, you can correct. Don't hang about though; you've only got a few minutes before your vote gets locked in.

Comment: Quite late, but maybe related: [Voting counted on wrong answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175388/voting-counted-on-wrong-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have never, ever seen this in all my voting across two years.