# Voting counted on wrong answer

Tags: bug, voting

In the last couple of months I observed strange behavior when up- or downvoting on answers on various occasions.

Within one post (containing several answers) my votes seem to switch answers: I upvoted on one answer but after I reload the page the upvote is instead displayed on a different answer (in one occasion even on the question).

I'm seeing this behavior on both Mac OS Safari and iOS Mobile Safari. I'm sure of at least three occasions of the bug (but remember more situations where I am unsure).

The bug might be connected to cases where I voted on an answer that has been edited after I loaded the page, but that's just a guess.

Answering the comments:

> It might help the developers to know which posts this applies to.

Agreed. I'll add a links to occasions where the bug happens from now on.

> what sort order in the answers are you using?

My sort order is usually by votes, but I think it happened with different settings, too.

> Also, does it ever seem votes are not counted at all? (Hence: might have ended up in a different question?

No, I never had a case of a disappearing vote. Votes just switch answers (or even to the question).

> might it indeed only happen AFTER you loaded new answers

No I don't think its connected to **new** answers. But I'm not totally sure about this.

> any ad blocker active?

I'm using AdBlock 2.5.56 on Desktop Safari. I'd use it on Mobile Safari if Apple would allow extensions, yet they don't :(

> Ah, you already wrote: *all the time...*

To me it happens maybe around 5–10% of the times I vote.

> I assume you see the vote-arrow that you clicked change its color to orange?

Yes, definitely.

> And I assume you're actually clicking the arrow, not using some keyboard navigation?

Right. (Tapping, on Mobile Safari, though).

> if it happens again, please try to remember if you already voted something else on the same page before doing the Ajax magic

I happened to me on the first vote in this post. I'm not sure if it's connected to AJAX. I had the problem with simple reloads, as well.

> Quite interesting that you're seeing it quite often, while I cannot reproduce it.

It's not *that* often. Sometimes I don't see if for a week or two.

> Also quite scary, when building web sites...

Yes. It does give me a bad feeling using SO as well. In some occasions I voted on one of two answers (of which one was good and the other very bad). Then I come back later and find that my upvote is locked in on the bad answer.

Bug occurrences:

- 2013-05-10 14:30 UTC+2: Downvote clicked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16482224, after reload triangles appear grey, orange downvote triangle instead on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16481962
- [Antony](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/209357/antony) wrote in the bounty message on May 5th, 11:12: *Just recently, I edited and upvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383356) which was at the bottom at that time, then come back 25 minutes later to see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383454) was upvoted.*
- Antony commented April 13th, 5:37: *I tried to downvote a wrong answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984604/replacing-text-within-a-string), but after that answer was removed, I found myself downvoted the question instead.*
- Antony commented April 8th, 18:36: *I tried to upvote the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886166/calculate-sundays-between-two-dates), went to see the possible duplicate and went back using the back button. What I saw was that the answer score was linked to the question score, and the page showed that I have upvoted the question instead of the answer. I didn't consider the back button before. Maybe that also has something to do with this bug? And the answer I tried to upvote was loaded with AJAX.*
- 2013-08-29 15:10 UTC+2: Downvoted https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510527/104790, after going back a while later (using the browser's back button, pointing to an older comment of me on the same page) I noticed the orange downvote triangle on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510507/104790. Reloading fixed the orange marker, then pointing to the answer I really downvoted on.
- 2013-09-02 17:30 UTC+2: Downvoted on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18566858/104790. Coming back after a while the downvote appears on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18567311/104790. Cannot change the vote since it's locked in. Interestingly the comment I added appeared on the correct answer.

Comment: Happens to me all the time, usually after new answers are loaded with AJAX.

Comment: It might help the developers to know which posts this applies to, so they might be able to browse some logs? Also, does it ever seem votes are not counted at all? (Hence: might have ended up in a *different* question? Votes are sent by post id, so answers are unrelated to questions, as for voting.)

Comment: Nikolai & @Antony, what sort order in the answers are you using? And Nikolai, might it indeed only happen AFTER you loaded new answers?

Comment: @Arjan I sort them by the number of votes (default). When a new answer comes in, it would appear at the top (regardless of the sorting). If I find it good and upvote it, then come back later to the question, I would see a different answer is upvoted. I have to unupvote that answer and vote on the one I initially intended to upvote.

Comment: In the HTML, each voting area has a hidden input, `<div class="vote"><input type="hidden" value="15853814">`, where `15853814` is the post number. While voting, that number is fetched using `return a.closest("div.vote").find("input").val()`. For me, in Chrome and Safari on a Mac, that works nicely, also after clicking *"1 new answer to this question"*.  What browser are you using, @Antony?

Comment: @Arjan Safari 6.0.2 on Mac

Comment: I'm on Safari 6.0.3 (on OS X 10.8.3) but I doubt that matters, @Antony. Do you feel it *always* is wrong when voting on dynamically loaded answers? I've tested a bit, sorted by votes, both with the dynamically loaded post being the first answer, or the second answer. All fine. I guess it's irrelevant, but: any ad blocker active?

Comment: (Ah, you already wrote: *all the time*...)

Comment: @Arjan No ad blockers. If it happens again, I will report here.

Comment: Meanwhile I also tried in Safari by first upvoting an existing answer, and only then loading the *"1 new answer to this question"*, and then (down)voting that. Same result; no problems for my tests. I still somehow expect that some sort of caching combined with the `a.closest("div.vote")` is the culprit... @Antony and Nikolai: *before* you reload the page, I assume you see the vote-arrow that you clicked change its color to orange? (And I assume you're actually clicking the arrow, not using some keyboard navigation?)

Comment: @Arjan I did click the arrow and it did change color. Sometimes the orange arrow would appear on a different answer after further AJAX load. A simple refresh would solve the problem. Sometimes the orange arrow would remain on the original answer, but after I leave and return to the question, it would appear on a different answer than the one I intended to upvote. Sometimes the arrow and the score would be linked to the question score (they move up and down simultaneously). Again a simple refresh would eliminate this weird behavior.

Comment: @Antony, if it happens again, please try to remember if you already voted something else on the same page before doing the Ajax magic? (Quite interesting that you're seeing it quite often, while I cannot reproduce it. Also quite scary, when building web sites...)

Comment: @Arjan and Antony Your questions are very helpful to provide important details, thank you. See my replies in main post.

Comment: I remember such a problem from the Moderator Elections...turned out to be a buggy beta-browser (balpha was not amused). Can you try with a different browser if that behavior also shows up?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I tried with all the last incarnations of Safari and remember the problem occuring from time to time even with older Safari versions. Also, the problem happens with Mobile Safari, too.

Comment: @Arjan Now this is very weird. I tried to upvote the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886166/calculate-sundays-between-two-dates), went to see the possible duplicate and went back using the back button. What I saw was that the answer score was linked to the question score, and the page showed that I have upvoted the question instead of the answer. I didn't consider the back button before. Maybe that also has something to do with this bug? And the answer I tried to upvote was loaded with AJAX.

Comment: Maybe not so odd, @Antony. Indeed, in Chrome the Back button always (as far as I know) shows me the old state. Like: with the votes known after the page was first loaded, and without any changes that were loaded by clicking some *"1 new answer to this question"*. In other words: when using Back *any* recent Ajax updates are just lost. Fine. However: not so much for Safari, which seems to reload the page when using the Back button. (My Safari has no extensions, and its Develop menu does NOT have *"Disable Caches"* activated.) Just different design, I'd say. (I mainly use Chrome.)

Comment: @Arjan Same thing happened again. I tried to downvote a wrong answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984604/replacing-text-within-a-string), but after that answer was removed, I found myself downvoted the question instead.

Comment: Hmm... we really need a "Voting Sandbox" here on Meta (like the formatting sandbox we already have) where voting is totally free and not counted towards the daily limit. Having this reproducing this problem should become much easier. :)

Comment: @Antony and Nikolai: any chance it only happens when using some mobile provider? (Some [are known](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120356/im-unable-to-join-chat-in-safari-on-my-iphone-when-on-my-mobile-network-o2/120369#120369) for injecting their JavaScript in any page one requests...)

Comment: @Arjan It happens in Safari on my MacBook Pro, using LAN.

Comment: @Sha, I once tested (without being able to reproduce the issue) by ensuring I undid my vote within 5 minutes. I was expecting to see erroneous Ajax requests right away, which explains why the issue is only visible on reload.

Comment: @Antony, do you know a little bit about debugging using Safari's web inspector?

Comment: @Arjan Yes. What do I need to do?

Comment: Oh, sorry, @Antony, that Web Inspector has changed a lot since I used it last. There must be an easier way, but it seems one needs to hit Option+Command+I to get get into the web inspector, then Ctrl+3 to get the Instrument tab, and then click the record button (big round bullet). Next, vote  and unvote (you don't even have to be logged in, I guess), stop recording, and see what's the URL of outgoing Ajax request. Something like `/posts/16381500/vote/2` for an upvote, or `/posts/16381500/vote/0` when undoing that vote. Here, that number should match the id of the answer you're voting on.

Comment: @Arjan So I get `/posts/175388/vote/0` and `/posts/175388/vote/2` on this question. Do you mean I do this next time when I upvote an answer?

Comment: Yes, @Antony, and it's easier: see the `XHRs` "folder" in the resources pane, after hitting Ctrl+1. Too bad they're ordered alphabetically, it seems... See also the `scripts` "folder" there. Anything funny...?

Comment: As for scripts, when logged in I see: adFeedback.js, adzerk_xxx, full.js, ga.js, jquery.min.js, js, loader.min.js, post-validation.js, prettify-full.js, quant.js, stub.js and wmd.js, @Antony.

Comment: Hmm, the answer to which Nikolai's May 10th downvote ended up with, has been deleted...

Comment: As for @M.NightDemonbobby's *"I remember such a problem from the Moderator Elections...turned out to be a buggy beta-browser"*, that's [My votes went boom!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135633/my-votes-went-boom/135648#135648) It seems that question doesn't help either, but given balpha's answer it might help if a developer peeks into the log files to see what has been received for the reported erroneous examples.

Comment: are there any news on this? It happens almost every single day to me. Safari 6.0.5 on OS X 10.8.4 I always have to come back to questions to see if my vote is on the correct answer. That sucks big time. Not sure if helpful, but latest question where I realized it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651636/how-to-call-tableview-delegate-self-in-static-library-in-ios

Comment: Just curious (I cannot help) but: still seeing this? ([How did I manage to “lock in a vote” on my answer from before it was posted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194832/how-did-i-manage-to-lock-in-a-vote-on-my-answer-from-before-it-was-posted) may be the funniest example, if related.)

Comment: @Matthias, next time it occurs, can you try to remember if new answers were posted (a notification was shown), and if you loaded those by clicking the message (which does NOT refresh the full page) before you voted? Or if you maybe used the browser's Back button?

Comment: @Arjan It just happened to me again after using the browser's back button. See incidents above.

Comment: Ah, as for the Back button: in that last incident you *noticed* when using the Back button to go back. But I wonder if the Back button could be *causing* this (probably in combination with Ajax loading of new posts), hence: when used *before* voting. As some (like you) see it happen quite often, you're either more careful, or it must be related to a browser, or to usage habits. (I myself often open links in a new tab, and then just close them rather than going backwards.)

Comment: @Arjan I'd also say I'm not a huge user of the browser's back and forward buttons. I also very much open links in tabs and close them when finished with this topic. But I agree that the bug seems to be triggered by a somewhat uncommon usage pattern.

Comment: I should add that I removed the downvote a couple of hours later after the answer was enhanced.

Comment: Anybody's still interested in my incidents?

Comment: It seems maybe only you and @Antony have seen this behaviour. Or: have *noticed* it...

Comment: @Arjan This still happens to me. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TeYNW.png) of how the score of the [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188845/how-to-find-profile-visitor) appears on one of the answers. That answer has never been downvoted that much and I could see the scores were synchronized as the question was downvoted. Yet I couldn't figure out what went wrong with the JS. It's hard to catch this bug as most of the time you have to revisit a question after voting to see if something is wrong.

Comment: Ah, but that might be new information? So in this case it's not just that somehow your vote ends up on the wrong post, but the total score also ends up on the wrong post. (I can imagine that if you'd vote when that happens, it would also register wrongly.) Did you vote on that question or answer yourself?

Comment: @Arjan No. I really should have done that. Maybe next time when it happens.

Comment: Okay, so maybe: in some occasions the votes are *shown* on the wrong post (either on page load, or after new votes come in, or after new or edited posts are loaded through Ajax/WebSockets). Next, voting also assigns them to the wrong post. That's much easier tested, as it doesn't involve voting to get to the first problem...! Did you take that screenshot just before you posted it? And do you recall if new answers, or edits to posts, were loaded before you saw it? And to be sure: Safari, right?

Comment: @Arjan Those new answers were loaded through AJAX, on Safari. That was an old screenshot that I saved on the hard drive when the bug occurred a few months ago but I forgot to post it. The bug still occurs from time to time, but I can't keep track of all of them.

Comment: Ah, Nikolai and @Antony, if the votes are already shown on the wrong post (on page load, or after some Ajax/WebSocket magic) *before* even voting, then that also explains why votes always seem to end up on posts *in the same question (aka "thread")*, and not on some random post in the Stack Overflow database... I think all starts with the votes being *shown* on the wrong post, somehow... Maybe it's related to sort order in combination with Ajax/WebSocket magic?

Comment: @Arjan I'm not sure about this theory. While I notice from time to time that my votes appear on the wrong answer, I *never* noticed answers to switch vote counts.

Comment: @Arjan I'm quite certain that I encountered two distinct cases: 1. After coming back my vote shows on the wrong answer but reloading makes it switch back to the correct post. 2. Again, after coming back my vote appears on the wrong answer but reloading does not fix it. On the contrary: Trying to remove the vote on the wrong post is not possible as it is already locked in. Voting on the correct answer is still possible, though.

Comment: I guess you're right, Nikolai: it seems that @Antony's [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TeYNW.png) shows *duplicated* votes on two different posts. So: Oded's [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188845/how-to-find-profile-visitor/188847#188847) showing *the same* votes as the question, and Oded's *real* votes being lost in action, in that screenshot. In the HTML source, I *assume* both posts would then have used the same `<div class="vote"><input type="hidden" value="188845">`, or something even more messy, which is then found by `a.closest("div.vote").find("input").val()`...

Comment: @Arjan Just had another case: Downvoted http://stackoverflow.com/a/18786898/104790, reload (which made answers to be reordered), now http://stackoverflow.com/a/18787240/104790 shows the downvote. Interesting is that before reload, the downvoted answer was on spot three, after reload the third spot is the other answer but shows the downvote (so the downvote stayed on the third answer). Might be coincidence, though. Another proper reload made the problem go away.

Comment: Still curious: did 2014 bring any solution? ;-)

Comment: Still curious: did spring bring any solution? (Cc: @Antony)

Comment: @Arjan I haven't been voting on answers lately, so I don't know. Plus, you have to revisit the page to check if the votes are correct, so it is very easy for it to slip under the radar.

Comment: @Arjan I'm not sure when the bug happend the last time but it's a while. I'll post when I see it again.