# How to find profile visitor?

Tags: support

I have search related question but I didn't get any satisfied response.

Is it possible to see which user has seen my profile?

Comment: Nope, that information is not available.

Comment: You don't. You can see how many times your profile has been visited, but not who by.

Comment: if my reputation is more than 1000 then i am able to see that or get some privillages for that?

Comment: @aliasgarvanak still no

Comment: @aliasgarvanak - Read [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188847/187824)

Comment: @tombull89 Tiny little clarification; that number actually shows how many users have viewed your profile. Once I've visited your profile once, it doesn't increment any more than that. (I have no reference immediately at hand for this claim - so I could even be wrong, but I think that's the case)

Comment: This is not linkedin and your profile section is empty, why you care about that? Usually ppl on SO would write their contact info if they are freelancer, its how it work there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Even us developers don't have that information readily available, nor do we intend to make it so.