# How did I manage to "lock in a vote" on my answer from before it was posted?

Tags: bug, voting, locked-votes

There are two problems with the following screenshot:

> [image]

1. It says that I voted on the answer 21 minutes before I took that screenshot, despite the answer only having been posted 3 minutes before I took that screenshot.
2. It says that I've voted on my own answer, which I believe shouldn't be possible.

How did these two things happen?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I downvoted the other answer to that question.

Comment: Aside: Why were you trying to downvote your own answer?

Comment: Is this on a clean refresh of the page? Any things you remember doing that might have caused the votes to get jumbled? Your answer correctly shows as a score of 0 when I load the question.

Comment: @StephenTG: I wasn't.

Comment: @animuson: No, and I'm seeing a score of 0 now too. I remember seeing my answer's score at -1 with a blue down-arrow, thinking that I might have accidentally clicked on it and been allowed to vote my own answer _down_ (though up upvoting my own answer should obviously not be allowed), so clicking on it in an attempt to undo the downvote, the score becoming -2, clicking it again in an attempt to undo that, and then seeing the red box.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe related: [Voting counted on wrong answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175388/voting-counted-on-wrong-answer).

Comment: (If you were seeing inbox notifications: sorry, I didn't fully read the above comments, so deleted my obsolete questions... Will remove this one soonish too.)

Comment: The only way such thing can happen as far as I can tell is when the HTML gets garbled somehow and the hidden input holding the post ID is changing place. So, what browser you have? Can you check with its dev tools the location of the hidden input with the post ID and maybe get some hint this way? :)

Comment: Would deleting the post and undeleting it reset the "post date"?

Comment: [Reproduced](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtsTYOY-68o) after manually changing the ID using the browser's dev tools. This confirm my previous comment.

Comment: @ColeJohnson no, the post date remains the same as the original.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I'm using Sarari 6.0.1